# DLinq morphed into which one -- Linq to SQL or the Entity Framework?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model, dynamic-linq

1. What happened to Dlinq? I heard a few years ago that it was abandoned.
2. Was some of its code used to create Linq to SQL or the ADO.NET Entity Framework? Which one? In other words, which of the two latter technologies are a new avatar of the old DLinq?

I am learning ADO.NET Entity Framework and since I am just starting out, I believe the answers to these questions will help me get a better understanding of the subject. I usually start out learning about the history and the background of a technical topic. It feels like a warm up exercise that gives me a boost in confidence and increases motivation to learn more. Also, it puts things in perspective, which other developers may not have.

Over the last few months, I've read Linq to Objects and Linq to SQL somewhat, and have also compared the boilerplate that's generated by Linq to SQL vs. that generated by the Entity Framework's Entity Model tooling.

I can appreciate the intrinsics somewhat as in, how the two models' `DataContext` / `ObjectContext` relate, and how the former uses `Table<T>` where the latter uses an `ObjectQuery`, both of which are `IQueryable` and thus support the standard Linq query operators.

Linq to SQL looks a lot more like a rip off of DLinq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLINQ became LINQ to SQL. LINQ to SQL is not a rip off; it's an evolution.